# How to use custom std::sort function?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std

Hi i have a vector of pointers, actually each pointer is an array, where each arrays is:

int a, int b, sequence of integers of variable size.

Example of unordered vector:

```
rows[0] => points to [1,2,...]
rows[1] => points to [2,1,...]
rows[2] => points to [3,1,...]
rows[3] => points to [1,4,...]
rows[4] => points to [1,1,...]
```

Example of output:

```
rows[0] => points to [1,1,...]
rows[1] => points to [1,2,...]
rows[2] => points to [1,4,...]
rows[3] => points to [2,1,...]
rows[4] => points to [3,1,...]
```

I need to sort this vector in this way I create the following custom compare function:

```
bool cmpRow(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b)
{
    //Mesmo id word
    if(a[0] == b[0])
    {

        return (a[1] < b[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        return (a[0] < b[0]);
    }        
}
```

and I'm using it the following way:

```
std::vector<unsigned int*> rows;
.
.
//Insert some stuffs 
.
.
std::sort (rows.begin(), rows.end(), cmpRow);
```

But the result isn't was I expected, can anyone help me with this issue?

**Edit:**

Actually the functions is alright, the problem was in a function inside a loop, this functions called the sort function more times than the necessary so the result wasn't the expected.

Comment: `std::sort` sorts the elements of the underlying container in the range *[first,last)*.The order `1,1,1,2,3` tells that your elements are indeed sorted, Note that the container elements are arrays in your case, so only those will be sorted and they are.Seems what you want is to sort the individual array elements of every vector element, this is not what `std::sort` does.

Comment: Also post your expected output.

Comment: What is the type of `rows`?  What result do you get (that you state is not the expected one)?

Comment: Please specify your (1) expected result and (2) observed result

Comment: I'm not posting the current output because the input is a large file, I think the problem is that I didn't understand what actually the sort  functions does internally.

Comment: You don't have to post your current output, just what you get on the input you listed in the question

Comment: I have just tried your code in my compiler (on the input given abouve, without the ellipses) and it produces the output you mentioned in your question.  I was under the impression it was your expected output.  If not, what do you expect on the input you have given in your question?

Comment: If you call the same `sort` function "more times than necessary", how does that change the result?  Once you sort something, subsequent sortings by the same mechanism should produce a result as if no sort was applied to the already sorted sequence.  `std::sort` does not guarantee to keep orders of "equal" values, but that does not apply in your example input and would not change the seen result anyway

Comment: It was printing something like: [1]. [1,2]. [1,2,3]. But when I check I didn't know it so I think it was [1,1,2,1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

Your function `cmpRow` sorts the given arrays in ascending order based on the first two members (by first comparing the first members, and if they are the same then comparing the second members).  This works fine and produces the results you reported, which are correct according to that logic.  If this was not the expected result, what result *did* you expect?

Answer (score -1):

Change your code like this?

```
bool cmpRow(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b)
{
    //You need to safeguard against empty/equal rows


    //Mesmo id word
    if(a[0] == b[0])
    {
        return cmpRow(a[1] < b[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        return (a[0] < b[0]);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I'm not cheking suck cases because there is not empty/equal rows in my case.

Comment: `a[1]` and `b[1]` are not pointers and `cmpRow` needs two parameters, so this code does not compile.  Did you mean `return cmpRow(&a[1], &b[1]);`?

Comment: you should check empty case because the recursive function has to terminate somewhere

Comment: This actually gonna solve the problem? Seems the same of my original code to me

Comment: Are you just using the first two elements only for sorting?

Comment: nakiya - my input cannot generate such 'bad cases'. PS: I don't know if this matters but I'm creating a Inverted File.